# My RecyclerView is duplicated every time I open activity

Tags: android-recyclerview

I have some problem with my project, and I will be very glad if anyone of you helps me. There is an activity in my app, where the only view is RecyclerView and everytime I open this activity, I need fill it, I do it like that:

```
 RecyclerView templatesRecycler;
 private MyRecyclerViewAdapter myRecyclerViewAdapter;
 int numberOfColumns = 2;
 //
 templatesRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.templatesListView);
 updateRecyclerView(MyCollections.getTemplatesTitles());



public void updateRecyclerView(ArrayList<MyTemplate> myTemplates){
        templatesRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        templatesRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
        myRecyclerViewAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, myTemplates, this);
        templatesRecycler.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
    }
```

I want to use class MyCollections, because there are a lot of RecyclerViews in my app, but I dont want to fill it myself everytime, so I create class MyCollections:

```
public class MyCollections {

    public static ArrayList<MyTemplate> templatesTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyCollections(){
        templatesTitles.add(new MyTemplate("Люди", R.drawable.ic_people));
        templatesTitles.add(new MyTemplate("Транспорт", R.drawable.ic_car));
        templatesTitles.add(new MyTemplate("Мебель", R.drawable.ic_furniture));
        templatesTitles.add(new MyTemplate("Фоны", R.drawable.ic_background));
        templatesTitles.add(new MyTemplate("Предметы", R.drawable.ic_tools));
        templatesTitles.add(new MyTemplate("Животные", R.drawable.ic_animal));
        templatesTitles.add(new MyTemplate("Природа", R.drawable.ic_nature));
        templatesTitles.add(new MyTemplate("Разметка листа", R.drawable.ic_sections));
        templatesTitles.add(new MyTemplate("Другое", R.drawable.ic_others));
    }

    public static ArrayList<MyTemplate> getTemplatesTitles() {
        return templatesTitles;
    }
}
```

By the way, here is my MyTemplate class:

```
public class MyTemplate {
    public String titleTemplate;
    public int drawableID;

    public String getTitleTemplate() {
        return titleTemplate;
    }

    public void setTitleTemplate(String titleTemplate) {
        this.titleTemplate = titleTemplate;
    }

    public int getDrawableID() {
        return drawableID;
    }

    public void setDrawableID(int drawableID) {
        this.drawableID = drawableID;
    }

    public MyTemplate(String titleTemplate, int drawableID){
        this.titleTemplate = titleTemplate;
        this.drawableID = drawableID;
    }

    public MyTemplate(){}
}
```

But here is the problem. Every time I open activity, my RecyclerView duplicates his elements, before I filled RecyclerView myself, and there wasnt such a problem. Please, help me, I am just beginner, so I dont know how I can fix this problem. Thanks!

Comment: You told every time you open your activity the data duplicates that means your getting duplicate data when you go to another activity and come back OR when you entirely close your application (from recent screen also) ?

Comment: when i go to another activity and come back. I realized, that problem is in MyCollection class, and now I am going to use SQL DataBase. But thanks for you responsing

Comment: Yup bro ... Every time you access `templatesTitles`, all the data will be added again and again because  `templatesTitles` is static